# Assert.AreEqual(...) gives me an System.FormatException

Tags: c#, unit-testing, assert, formatexception

```
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual, "The value returned for {0}'s Foo method should be 'Bar'.",
            typeof(Calculator));

Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual, "The value returned for {0}'s Foo method should be 'Bar'.",
            typeof(Calculator).Name);
```

Both of these lines throw a:

Test method MyTesting.FooTest threw exception: 
System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.

---

> System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat(IFormatProvider provider,
>   String format, Object[] args)
>   System.String.Format(IFormatProvider
>   provider, String format, Object[] args)
>   MyTesting.FooTest() in
>   C:\TFS\Scratchpad\MyLibrary\Unit Testing\FooTest.cs: line 195

The strange thing is I only get an exception if my Unit Test fails, when it passes I don't get this exception. I'm not expecting an exception though, instead it should have Failed due to the assertion, not because the unit test itself threw an exception.

Comment: Can you post the whole test?  Are you sure those lines threw the exception?  FormatException usually is an issue with Parse() in incorrect format.

Comment: No repro. This line of code runs fine on my PC.

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare: MSTest and yes, the exception points to that line.

Comment: It's not going to fail if `expected == actual`, because the asserted condition is satisfied and no attempt is made to format the string.

Comment: You did copy/paste the exact line, right? And add the lines just before and after this one too, just to be sure.

Comment: Also, is that the entire stack trace? The stack trace should show a call to `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.Assert.AreEqual`. This is suspicious.

Comment: @Jim: That's what I'm thinking too, it really sounds like it's coming from another line.  What line is line 195 in FooTest.cs?  Can we see the whole test?

Answer (score 1):

Make a test to be sure that your object Calculator is not null before your equality test.

This kind of error will occur in this particular case in a string format.

Answer (score 0):

Try to not use a formatted string and see if it still fails. I just ran into this same issue today trying to do an assert on structs, and doing this stopped my assert from throwing a format exception. It seems to have problems with formatted strings. (I'm using ms test)

```
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual,"The value returned for " + typeof (Calculator) + "'s Foo method should be 'Bar'.");
Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual, "The value returned for " + typeof(Calculator) + "'s Foo method should be 'Bar'.");
```

I don't like building strings like this but it was the only way I could get my test to run properly.